# Building profile page, trying to pull 'name' from Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a profile page that pulls a new user's 'name' from my Firestore database. Currently, I am getting an error (specifically with the rowCell line). Does anyone have any ideas or other better ways to do this?
Thank you!

Tried alternative functions to replace the 'rowCell' line.

Right now, values from Firestore are not pulling into the app.

```
class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final String userId;
  ProfileWidget (this.userId);
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            rowCell(user.name, 'Name'),
        ],);

          },
    );}}

class User{
  final int name;
  final DocumentReference reference;

  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : name = map['name'];

  User.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't get the documents from your `snapshot.data`. To do so you have to use `snapshot.data.documents`. In this [post](https://flutterdoc.com/loading-data-from-firestore-with-flutter-c42c520f6ee5) is an example of how to do that.

Code example from post:

```
return snapshot.data.documents
    .map((document) => new Text(document['some_field']).toList()
```

> To access fields from a document you can do so as shown above with document[‘some_field’]. Here we use our document reference from our map operation and then access a piece of data from that document using the field name as an accessor.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your snapshots when it has data before return your widget :
`if(snapshot.hasData){
User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            rowCell(user.name, 'Name'),
        ],);
}`

Comment: thank you, is this how you would recommend the implementations? It still shows an error                                              
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
        User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            rowCell(user.name, 'Name'),
          ],);
        );}}

Comment: class ProfileWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  final String userId;
  ProfileWidget (this.userId);
      @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(userId).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(snapshot.hasData){
        User user = User.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data);
        return Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            rowCell(user.name, 'Name');
        } else {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      }

Comment: i have made changes to the code and it is now as above ^. specifically, the error now says 'the method rowCell isn't defined for the class 'ProfileWidget'

Answer (score 0):

**It will be better if you post your error.**

According to you error is in `rowCell` then it means it is unable to build the widget *(I guess as you haven't mentioned the error)*.

Some Suggestions:
**Suggestion 1**:

```dart
builder:(context, snapshot){
  if(snapshot.hasData){
    // Process the data and return the widget.
  }
  else{
    // IMPORTANT: You have to return a widget or will get error.
    // Return the widget that should be shown during processing like:
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}
```

**Suggestion 2**: Are you sure `User.name` is an `int`? Usually it is `String`.

**Suggestion 3**: `FutureBuilder` will be more useful if you only need to fetch data once and build the page but if you need to update it automatically then you are using the correct widget.

If it doesn't help then post your error.
Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to use ```else``` block when implementing the answer by @Nhật Trần

Comment: According to what you said in the comments section of @Nhật Trần, are you sure, you have defined rowCell method properly? Can you post that too? Sorry can't write comment in other answer, don't have enough reputation.